# Backplane connector adapter

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, product-testing

I have a backplane.

A backplane is a PCB which more or less serves as a hub for other PCBs. The other PCBs connect to it through its "backplane connectors" and it routes the numerous quantity of signals between those connected PCBs.

On my backplane, the connector ports (backplane headers) were designed too close for testing.

Is anyone aware of backplane-connector right angle adapters such that I could plug into the original header connector, adapt at a right angle, and then
lay a board on its side to plug in at that right angle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more searching and asking,
I think the answer is that
this does not exist.

It makes sense,
since the connection isn't particularly firm.